# How to share internet connection between two computers one which is connected to a dongle

Tags: internet, usb-drive, lan, connection-sharing

I have a dongle connected on an ubuntu laptop.

I couldn't find a way out to share internet using WiFi.

How can I share internet over a LAN cable?

Does I require a cross-over cable?

Any extra settings?

Comment: try Connection Bridge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing internet connection via LAN cable.
Here are the steps:

PC Sharing Connection
PC that will share connection
Open your Network Manager via the Network Icon on the Unity Panel:

Goto the **Edit Connections** option and click on it.

Select the Wired connection you wish to edit and double click on it or select the EDIT button.

You will appear on the Wired Tab (Again). This time, go to the IPv4 Settings if you are using IPv4 or IPv6 if you are using that one. On the Method option select Share to Other Computers. Now SAVE. You are done.

Now just connect the 2 computers and you are done.

### Client PC

PC That will receive Shared Internet Connection (Depends on Network Setup)
Open your Network Manager via the Network Icon on the Unity Panel:

Goto the **Edit Connections** option and click on it.

Select the Wired connection you wish to edit and double click on it or select the EDIT button.

There on the Wired Tab, go to the IPv4 Settings if you are using IPv4. On the Method option select Manual. The options in Addresses will be editable now. Add the IP you want, the Mask you need and the IP of the PC that is sharing the connection.

> Eg:
>
> The IP of the Client PC will be `192.168.0.2`, the Mask is `255.255.255.0` to imply that is a Class C (LAN) network and `192.168.0.1` to mention that the computer sharing the connection has the IP `192.168.0.1` with it. Additionally add the same IP of the computer sharing the connection to the DNS Servers.

This should cover all the possible scenarios in a home LAN when one wants to share the internet connection over Wired cable.